# How do I scrape HTML that is rendered in the browser rather than JSON response?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Let's say I have an endpoint: [Example]

```
http://domain.website.com/dashboard
```

- If I hit this URL in postman, I get a JSON response.
- If I hit this URL in browser, and I 'view-page-source', I see
  JSON
- But if I inspect element, I see HTML rendered

And obviously, if I request with Python,

```
r = requests.get('http://domain.website.com/dashboard')
print(r.text)
```

I get JSON.

By my understanding the FrontEnd Javascript Framework is rendering the HTML using the JSON response.

But my usecase is to crawl few links in the HTML, but I get only JSON response using Requests module. In that case, how do I get HTML instead of JSON?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to get a response rendered in HTML?

Comment: Yes. I want HTML response. I'm getting only the JSON response. But when I inspect element that page in the browser, I see the HTML response (which is what I want)

Comment: Aren't those links already available in the JSON response? The only way you can get the rendered html response is by emulating a browser, which you can do with selenium.

Comment: No. Links aren't in that JSON. Or else I would have parsed JSON to get those links. So selenium is the only way? I have another problem. For each page, let's say /dashboard, many API calls are being made. Python requests is unidirectional :(

Comment: try to add `Accept: ...` to your header, but as my expect it still response in JSON because rendering in browser is better than in server.